# How to extract file paths from a text file

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c, parsing

I am looking for a tool / code in C#, or C++ / C that can extract file paths from a file e.g.

File.txt:

```
Lorem Impusum
C:\Windows\System32\test.exe
C:\Users\Limited\Downloads.txt
 testing 123
```

So it would output File.txt as follows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\test.exe
C:\Users\Limited\Downloads.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return what you're after, assuming you've loaded the contents of your file into a `List<string>` or `string[]`

```
        var result = potentialPaths.Where(Path.IsPathRooted).ToList();
```

Also, this is C#.

Comment: Note that this might throw an `ArgumentException` when the other lines in the file/`potentialPaths` contain totally arbitrary text, which contains characters from `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`. Arguably, however, the example the OP gave is a little rough, so it is probably OK anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at c# [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).

Google is your friend.

Comment: GetDirectoryName is the sixth method listed. There are many other useful methods there as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex, something like:

```
"([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+\\\\?"
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an example how to do it in C++ here: http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Reference.pdf

Here is an excerpt:

```
// windows path can start with a server name or letter
auto start_server = "\\\\" & +path_chars - '\\';
auto start_drive = r_alpha() & ':';
auto simple_path = (start_server | start_drive) & *('\\' & +path_chars);
auto quoted_path = '"' & (start_server | start_drive) &
*('\\' & +(space | path_chars)) & '"';
// path can be either simple or quoted
auto path = simple_path | quoted_path;
// rule to extract all paths
std::vector<std::wstring> paths;
size_t length = 0;
auto extract_paths = *(*(r_any() - (path >> e_push_back(paths) >> e_length(length)))
& r_advance(length));
```

You can customize the rules for your purposes. The rules will also work for unicode and binary files, no change necessary.